# How to fix Incorrect syntax near '=' error in stored procedure that uses dynamic SQL

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I attempted to add some additional columns to an existing stored procedure. This entailed not only adding the columns but also creating a LEFT JOIN subquery to gather the additional columns that is commented on " Addition of Sales and Warranties totals". Now, when I execute this code within my stored procedure, I'm getting an error in the SQL command.

I've tried opening a new query window and trying to recreate the query in the proper format to execute it, but I get the following errors: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 60
Incorrect syntax near ' + case when isnull(@TaxHeaders,') = ' then '.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 117
Incorrect syntax near ' + case when isnull(@TaxHeaders,') = ' then '.

I've also tried changing the location of my LEFT JOIN query (SWT,GT) above the T and T1 LEFT JOIN that includes the pivot.

```
CREATE Procedure [GP].[spInvoiceReprintsSummary] 
@CompanyKey varchar(2)=5, 
@ParentCustomerNum varchar(255)='BCAA01',       --'AAANYCITY',      --'AAANPENN01', --'CAAQUEBE01',     --'BCAA01',     --'CAAQUEBE01', 
@StartDateKey varchar(8)=20130306, 
@EndDateKey varchar(8)=20130315,
@TaxHeaders varchar(255)='HST,GST,PST,QST'      --'GST, QST'
As 
Begin
Declare @SQL as varchar(max)
Set @SQL = '
Select S.CompanyKey, S.TaxScheduleID, S.CustomerKey, S.ParentCustomerNum, S.StationID, S.CustomerName, S.DocumentTypeKey, S.DocumentNum, Case When Left(S.DocumentNum, 2)=''ST'' Then 0 ELSE 1 End As EligibleDiscount,S.ExtendedPrice,S.PurchaseOrderNum, DocumentDate, S.TaxAmount, SWT.SalesTotal, SWT.WarrantiesTotal, S.TerritoryId ' + case when isnull(@TaxHeaders,'') = '' then '' else ',' + @TaxHeaders end  + ' From
(
--Get distinct documents
Select --Top 100
SD.CompanyKey, SD.TaxScheduleID, CS.CustomerKey, CS.ParentCustomerNum, CS.StationID, CS.CustomerName, SD.DocumentTypeKey, SD.DocumentNum,SD.PurchaseOrderNum, convert(datetime,convert(varchar, DateKey, 112)) As DocumentDate,sum(SD.TaxAmount) as TaxAmount, sum(SD.ExtendedPrice) As ExtendedPrice, CS.TerritoryId From GP.SalesDetail SD
Inner Join GP.Customers CS
on SD.CustomerKey = CS.CustomerKey
Where CS.ParentCustomerNum= ''' + @ParentCustomerNum + ''' And SD.DateKey Between ' +  @StartDateKey + ' and ' +  @EndDateKey + ' And SD.CompanyKey = ' + @CompanyKey + ' And SD.PostStatus = 1 And SD.VoidStatus = 0
Group by SD.CompanyKey, SD.TaxScheduleID, CS.CustomerKey, CS.ParentCustomerNum, CS.StationID, CS.CustomerName, SD.DocumentTypeKey, SD.DocumentNum,SD.PurchaseOrderNum, convert(datetime,convert(varchar, DateKey, 112)), CS.TerritoryId
--Order By SD.PurchaseOrderNum, SD.DocumentTypeKey
) S
---Addition of sales and warranties totals
LEFT JOIN(

SELECT  CASE WHEN GroupName = ''SALES''  then sum(QuantitySold) else 0 end as SalesTotal,CASE WHEN GroupName = ''WARRANTIES'' then sum(QuantitySold) else 0 end as WarrantiesTotal, DocumentNum, CompanyKey FROM
(SELECT 
SD.QuantitySold , DocumentNum , SD.CompanyKey
,CASE WHEN I.userDefItemClass1 = ''BATTERY/RETURN'' AND SD.QuantitySold >= 0 THEN ''SALES'' 
WHEN I.userDefItemClass1 = ''BATTERY/RETURN'' AND SD.QuantitySold < 0 THEN ''RETURNS'' 
WHEN I.ItemNum = ''RESTOCKING FEE'' AND sd.ExtendedPrice >= 0 THEN ''RETURNS'' 
WHEN I.ItemNum = ''RESTOCKING FEE'' AND sd.ExtendedPrice < 0 THEN ''SALES''
WHEN I.userDefItemClass1 = ''WARRANTY'' THEN ''WARRANTIES''
WHEN I.userDefItemClass1 = ''NRF'' THEN ''RECYCLING FEES'' 
WHEN I.userDefItemClass1 = ''CORES'' THEN ''SPENT BATTERIES''
WHEN I.ItemNum IN (''PU2'',''PU4.3'') AND sd.ExtendedPrice > 0 THEN ''RETURNS'' 
WHEN I.ItemNum IN (''PU2'',''PU4.3'') AND sd.ExtendedPrice < 0 THEN ''SALES'' 
ELSE ''OTHER'' END AS GroupName
FROM GP.SalesDetail AS SD 
INNER JOIN GP.Items AS I ON SD.ItemKey = I.ItemKey 
Inner Join GP.Customers CS on SD.CustomerKey = CS.CustomerKey
WHERE
CS.ParentCustomerNum= '' + @ParentCustomerNum + '' And SD.DateKey Between ' +  @StartDateKey + ' and ' +  @EndDateKey + ' And SD.CompanyKey = ' + @CompanyKey + ' And SD.PostStatus = 1 And SD.VoidStatus = 0 
) GN
GROUP BY DocumentNum, GroupName, CompanyKey
) SWT
ON  S.Companykey = SWT.CompanyKey And S.DocumentNum = SWT.DocumentNum
Left join (
--Pivot the Tax Types
Select Companykey, DocumentTypeKey, DocumentNum ' + case when isnull(@TaxHeaders,'') = '' then '' else ',' + @TaxHeaders end  + ' From (
SELECT     SD.CompanyKey,TD.DocumentTypeKey, TD.DocumentNum, TS.TaxDetailLabel, SUM(TD.TaxAmount) AS TaxAmount
FROM         GP.TaxSchedules AS TS INNER JOIN
(SELECT     SD.CompanyKey, SD.TaxScheduleId, SD.DocumentTypeKey, SD.DocumentNum
FROM          GP.SalesDetail SD
Inner Join GP.Customers CS
on SD.CustomerKey = CS.CustomerKey
Where CS.ParentCustomerNum= ''' + @ParentCustomerNum + ''' And SD.DateKey Between ' +  @StartDateKey + ' and ' +  @EndDateKey + ' And SD.CompanyKey = ' + @CompanyKey + ' And SD.PostStatus = 1 And SD.VoidStatus = 0 
GROUP BY SD.CompanyKey, SD.TaxScheduleId, SD.DocumentTypeKey, SD.DocumentNum) AS SD 
ON TS.CompanyKey = SD.CompanyKey AND TS.TaxScheduleId = SD.TaxScheduleId 
INNER JOIN GP.TaxDetails AS TD ON TD.DocumentNum = SD.DocumentNum AND TD.DocumentTypeKey = SD.DocumentTypeKey AND 
TD.LineItemSequenceNum = 0 AND TD.TaxDetailID = TS.TaxDetailId AND TD.CompanyKey = TS.CompanyKey
GROUP BY SD.CompanyKey,TD.DocumentTypeKey,TD.DocumentNum, TS.TaxDetailLabel
) T
Pivot (sum(TaxAmount) For TaxDetailLabel In (' + case when isnull(@TaxHeaders,'') = '' then 'Tax' else @TaxHeaders end  + ')) as PVT
) T1
on S.Companykey = T1.CompanyKey And S.DocumentTypeKey = T1.DocumentTypeKey And S.DocumentNum = T1.DocumentNum'
--print @SQL
Exec (@SQL)
End
```

I expect an output of the original result set including the new columns for SalesTotal and WarrantiesTotal

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`CASE 
    WHEN isnull(@taxheaders,'') = '' 
        then '' 
    ELSE ',' + @taxheaders 
END`

with

`CASE 
    WHEN @taxheaders IS NULL 
        THEN '' 
    ELSE ',' + @taxheaders`

This should fix the error. Thanks..

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, but this didn't seem to fix the issue

Comment: Can you post the current error message that you are getting?

Comment: I think i see the actual issue now. You are checking the field `TaxDetailLabel` among a set of values using an `in` keyword which should be string values so they should be sorrounded by quotes for the value `Tax` and also for the variable `@taxheaders`